# Windows Batch - Passing space over variable for use in ADB command

Tags: android, windows, batch-file, adb

I am currently using a batch script to transfer multiple files to multiple android devices using ADB.

I am currently struggling to get the argument to ignore the spaces in the output filepath.

I am currently calling an external batch file "**adb+.bat**" which contains the code:

```
@echo off
SET ARGUMENTS=%*

if "%ARGUMENTS%" == "" (
    GOTO EOF
)

SET "ARGUMENTS=%ARGUMENTS:""="%"

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
:: INSTALL ON ALL ATTACHED DEVICES ::
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%A IN ('adb devices') DO (
    SET IS_DEV=%%B
    if "!IS_DEV!" == "device" (
        SET SERIAL=%%A
        echo "adb -s !SERIAL! %ARGUMENTS%"
        call adb -s !SERIAL! %ARGUMENTS%
    )
)
ENDLOCAL

:EOF
```

This is then used in the main **.bat** to pass the argument to multiple devices.

```
cmd.exe /c @for /f "delims=" %%l in ('dir /b ^"%~sdp0PDF\*.pdf^"') do adb+.bat push "%~sdp0PDF\%%l" "/sdcard/PDF/%%l"
```

The filenames contain spaces that cannot be removed.
This is causing the following error:

```
Z:\Customer\Model\Build Deployment Software\Build BAT Files>adb+.bat push "Z:\CUSTOP~1\MODEL\BUILDD~1\BUILDB~1\PDF\Test PDF.pdf" "/sdcard/PDF/Test PDF.pdf"
PDF.pdf" "/sdcard/PDF/Test was unexpected at this time.
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
if "%ARGUMENTS%" == "" (
    GOTO EOF
)
```

With:

```
if not defined ARGUMENTS (
    GOTO EOF
)
```

You are assigning `%*` to `ARGUMENTS`.

`%*` can have double quoted arguments so when you use double quotes
to surround `%ARGUMENTS%`, then the pairing of the quotes is now
different.

For example, if you have a value of `"a b"` in `%ARGUMENTS%`
and you add quotes, you get `""a b""`, which is interpreted as
 `""`, `a`, `b` and `""`.

This results in an error when you try to do a comparison as you have
multiple values between the `if` and the `==`.

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach to the issue. Rather than calling an external .bat,  I have used the script directly in my main .bat.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%a IN ('adb devices') DO (
    SET IS_DEV=%%b
    if "!IS_DEV!" == "device" (
        SET SERIAL=%%a
            call adb -s !SERIAL! push -p "%~sdp0PDF" "/sdcard/PDF"
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
```